# It is possible to create an administrative panel with web flutter and use it in a mobile flutter application

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, flutter-web

It is possible to create an administrative panel with web flutter and use it in a mobile flutter application?

and what is most suitable for the administrative panel? flutter web or php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have an web administrative panel and use it on a mobile device as well, I'm currently in the process of building one. The best thing with Flutter is that you can build with one code base and use it over a variety devices and Operating Systems. And its pretty easy to make responsive as Flutter was initially built for Mobile.

[My Admin Dashboard in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F1um.png)

The only thing you need to be weary of, is Flutter Web is still in BETA, and has issues from time to time. PHP has been around for years and would be great for a Web Admin Panel, and can be made responsive, but would need to be opened in the browser - which isn't as intuitive as an app.

Comment: Hello, jackson thanks for the answer, your panel is very cool, I have another question, how is your panel communicating with your app? did you develop an api?

Comment: In this particular case I run two flutter apps (Admin Dashboard & Enquiry App) - The admin dashboard can be used as an app, but it is specifically used in the web, and the Enquiry app is specifically used on tablets. I use Firebase to store my data which both apps have access too.